# Can a ClickOnce application return a value to the browser

Tags: asp.net, webserver, clickonce

I have an online ClickOnce application that launches from a web page. After the application is closed, I would like the user to return to that page with some results passed from the application. Is this possible? or back to the web server? Any online examples of this

Comment: ClickOnce technology can't give to you this possibility and you need manually returns some your data back to server and pass it to your browser.

Comment: Any suggestions how to do that?